# Show each response of php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

I use ajax type for send data to php file and get response and show. In my php file i have

```
while($i<14){ echo $i.'<br />'; $i++;}
```

that return 14 replay.

So, my webpage when call data with ajax method, after some secounds, show all 14 results. But i want get live response from my ajax file.

So i want my webpage show :

```
1
...
```

and then

```
1
2
....
```

etc

This is my Ajax code that return all response together in `shower` div.
I want get live responses. for any responses that sent from php file

```
function update_table(uptype){
    $("#shower").html("Loading...");
    var dataString = 'type=' + uptype;    
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "motor.php",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html) {
                $("#shower").html(html);
              }
        });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you want hire someone to write it for you, you are on the wrong website. Please try it yourself and ask a specific question if something goes wrong, showing your attempt and details about the errors you get.

Comment: @GolezTrol no, i don`t want any one write this code for me! . i`m write ajax code and any things work correctly. just all of my response show together that i want know how i can show responses like a logs.

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm edit my question and add my ajax code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible with your current setup.

Think of an ajax-call to a PHP-script is like visiting a website like www.example.com/yourscript.php
PHP will then server-side render a code which is sent to your web-browser. This is a one call and one answer operation. PHP will not dynamically add elements to the website. Neither will it then be able to dynamically send answers to your ajax-call. What you have to do to solve this is storing the progress of the PHP script somewhere, and do several calls to get a update on the status.